# UIScrollView in different versions - iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I'm working on a UIScrollView in iPad. The Scroll view scrolls smoothly in iOS 5.0 ,but the animation of scrolling is not smoother in Versions below 5.0.

Is there any specific customization be done to handle this?Should I add some more functionality to run  UIScrollView in iOS 4.x?

-- I am facing this problem when adding custom UIView into the UIScrollView.

Working Code :

```
{
  timeLineScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500);
  float posX = 0;

  for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
  {
          UIView *samView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(posX, 10, 500, 300)];
          posX = posX + 500;
          [timeLineScrollView addSubview:samView];
  }

   timeLineScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500*10, timeLineScrollView.frame.size.height);

}
```

Not Working Code :

```
 {   
  timeLineScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500);
  float posX = 0;
  for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
  {
          CustomView *samView = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(posX, 10, 500, 300)];
          posX = posX + 500;
          [timeLineScrollView addSubview:samView];
  }

   timeLineScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500*10, timeLineScrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

The Custom View :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withEvent:(VisitHistoryEvent*)eventDetails
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

      complaint = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    }
  return self;
 }



 -(void)layoutSubviews
{
    complaint.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20);
    [self addSubview:complaint];
 }
```

Comment: -1. There is not enough detail of the problem you are encountering, or enough clarity in the request for help. Please provide a more concrete example of where the problem occurs in order that people might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch... If you tried to create one UIView as a subview for the UIScrollView (with a width of 3000 to match your content) and added your UILabels to that view rather than directly to the UIScrollView, perhaps then iOS will be able to cache it and give you better perf.